# Как на javascript создать своё событие?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Интересует, возможно ли на `javaScript` создать свое событие, чтоб на него можно было поставить слушатель события.

Например есть два блока, как создать событие если кто-то кликнул на первый блок, это событие `click_1`, а если на второй блок, событие `click_2`.

Нужно, чтоб была возможность повесить на эти события обработчик, как на обычный клик:

```
$( "#target" ).click_1(function() {
  alert( "click_1" );
});
```

Пример разметки:

```css
.block_1{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.block_2{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_1"> 1 </div>
<div class="block_2"> 2 </div>
```

Как такое реализовать на `js`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Благодаря методам `trigger` и `triggerHandler` (`triggerHandler` можно условно назвать урезанной версией `trigger`) вы можете генерировать стандартные и кастомные события
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ 
http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Вы также можете группировать общие события (события одного компонента например), используя namespace https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

```
$element.on('event.namespace', function (e) {
  ...
});
...
$element.trigger('event.namespace');
```

Однако в вашем примере на самом деле лучше подписываться на события конкретного элемента:

```js
$('.block_1').on('click', function () {
  alert('Block 1');
});
$('.block_2').on('click', function () {
  alert('Block 2');
});
```

```css
.block_1 {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.block_2 {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block_1">1</div>
<div class="block_2">2</div>
```

Можно даже воспользоваться единым обработчиком:

```js
$('.js-block').on('click', function () {
  alert('Block ' + $(this).data('blockNum'));
});
```

```css
.block_1 {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.block_2 {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block_1 js-block" data-block-num="1">1</div>
<div class="block_2 js-block" data-block-num="2">2</div>
```

А делегирование позволит отлавливать события динамически создаваемых элементов:

```js
var $body = $('body'),
    addBlock = (function  () {
  var $lastBlock = $('.js-block').last(),
      className = ['block_2', 'block_1'],
      counter = 0 || $lastBlock.data('blockNum');
  
  return function () {
    var $block = $('<div/>');
    counter++;
    $block.data('blockNum', counter);
    $block.addClass(className[counter % 2]).addClass('js-block').text(counter);
    $body.append($block);
  };
})();

$body.on('click', '.js-block', function () {
  alert('Block ' + $(this).data('blockNum'));
  addBlock();
});
```

```css
.block_1 {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.block_2 {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block_1 js-block" data-block-num="1">1</div>
<div class="block_2 js-block" data-block-num="2">2</div>
```

Но если вам все же нужно ловить глобально генерируемые события (только не делайте этого в условиях данного примера - это будет не очень хорошим тоном), воспользуйтесь паттерном "Медиатор". Его простую реализацию для jquery можно найти здесь https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-tiny-pubsub

```js
/*! Tiny Pub/Sub - v0.7.0 - 2013-01-29
* https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-tiny-pubsub
* Copyright (c) 2013 "Cowboy" Ben Alman; Licensed MIT */
(function($) {

  var o = $({});

  $.subscribe = function() {
    o.on.apply(o, arguments);
  };

  $.unsubscribe = function() {
    o.off.apply(o, arguments);
  };

  $.publish = function() {
    o.trigger.apply(o, arguments);
  };

}(jQuery));

$('.js-block').on('click', function() {
  $.publish('click_' + $(this).data('blockNum'));
});

$.subscribe('click_1', function() {
  alert('Block 1');
});

$.subscribe('click_2', function() {
  alert('Block 2');
});
```

```css
.block_1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.block_2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block_1 js-block" data-block-num="1">1</div>
<div class="block_2 js-block" data-block-num="2">2</div>
```

Советую подробнее прочитать про паттерны проектирования http://largescalejs.ru/

Comment: стоит еще добавить про namespace у событий

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за предложение. Внес исправления.

Answer (score 3):

На чистом JS смотрите [Создание и вызов событий](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Events/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9):

```js
var click1 = new Event('click_1')
  ,click2 = new Event('click_2')
  ,b1 = document.getElementById('block_1')
  ,b2 = document.getElementById('block_2')
;

// слушать события
b1.addEventListener('click_1', function (e) { console.log("Clicked 1"); }, false);
b2.addEventListener('click_2', function (e) { console.log("Clicked 2"); }, false);

// вызвать события
b2.dispatchEvent(click2);
```

```css
#block_1,#block_2{width: 50px;height: 50px;margin: 10px;text-align: center;float: left;cursor: pointer;}#block_1{background-color: aqua}#block_2{background-color: chartreuse}
```

```html
<div id="block_1">1</div>
<div id="block_2">2</div>
```

При этом стандартное событие клика остаётся, и если хотите вызывать созданные события по клику, надо ловить клик, и из его обработчика делать `dispatchEvent(ваше нестандартное событие)`